# Mass deletion of data in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I've been trying to mass delete the data of 2 datatable but the error came out was:

An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near ','.

My code is:

```
protected void BtnCleanUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sql4 = @"DELETE FROM medicine, batch_number)";
        if (DBMgr.ExecuteSQL(sql4) >= 1)
        {
            LtlDatabaseMessage.Text = "Deletion successful";
        }
        else
        {
            LtlDatabaseMessage.Text = "Unexpected error";
        }
    }
```

I don't know why there is an error near ','

Comment: You have a closing bracket after `batch_number` but not open bracket. I'm not sure what your query's trying to do though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If medicine and batch_number is both table, you can use this. I hope it will work for you.

```
protected void BtnCleanUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql4 = @"DELETE FROM medicine; DELETE FROM batch_number;";
    if (DBMgr.ExecuteSQL(sql4) >= 1)
    {
        LtlDatabaseMessage.Text = "Deletion successful";
    }
    else
    {
        LtlDatabaseMessage.Text = "Unexpected error";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Line:

```
string sql4 = @"DELETE FROM medicine, batch_number)";
```

Should read

```
string sql4 = @"DELETE FROM medicine";
string sql5 = @"DELETE FROM batch_number";
```